# Django using aggregate MAX

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following...

```
r = Region.objects.get_location_name(user.location)
```

Which returns:

```
[<Region: Great Britain>, <Region: Europe>]
```

Next I want to only return the object with the MAX highest `parent`.

I have tried this:

```
r = Region.objects.get_location_name(user.location).aggregate(Max('level'))
```

but this does not return an object it returns...

```
{'level__max': 1}
```

Why?

Comment: Because that's what `aggregate` does. Perhaps you want `annotate`? But it's hard to tell without seeing your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `order_by`: Sort the queryset by descending 'level' and then get the first item by doing `queryset[0]`.

I *think* your code should look like

```
r = Region.objects.get_location_name(user.location).order_by('-level')[0]
```

Comment: Yes that would work, I misunderstood what annotate did.